# Longest Common Subsequence in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

Is there any possible algorithm for finding length of Longest Subsequence in O(n) time? I know about O(nlogn).

Comment: You should ask straight down for an O(1) one...

Comment: messi. Amazing footballer, not quite so amazing at cs

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no algorithm of LCS which will give you result with O(n) complexity. O(nlgn) is highest performance of this problem.